# Getting a Macintosh Plus up and running...?

Tags: mac, floppy

I found an old Mac Plus, and when I turned it on, it had a flashing image of a floppy drive on the screen. Does that mean I have to have a OS floppy? Or can it only be run using an empty one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Macintosh Plus requires a boot disk to start up; you'll need some way of writing an 800K floppy disk. [This thread has some information](http://68kmla.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1174), but it seems at the time you needed an old Mac to create the disk.